# Force AutoFixture to use the greediest constructor

Tags: c#, autofixture

I have a data type with multiple constructors and I need AutoFixture to choose the greediest (one with the most parameters). The default behaviour is to choose the constructor with the smallest number.

The author's blog post, http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/03/24/HowAutoFixtureCreatesObjects.aspx doesn't seem to imply there's a way of overriding this behaviour, so is it possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[This is certainly possible](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/19/ConstructorStrategiesForAutoFixture.aspx).

To change the strategy for a single type (`MyClass`):

```
fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => c.FromFactory(
    new MethodInvoker(
        new GreedyConstructorQuery())));
```

To change the strategy across the board:

```
fixture.Customizations.Add(
    new MethodInvoker(
        new GreedyConstructorQuery()));
```

---

As it turns out, however, using GreedyConstructorQuery across the board is most likely problematic, as the following code snippet demonstrates. Imagine a class with this constructor:

```
public Foo(string name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
```

This test will throw an exception:

```
[Test]
public void GreedyConstructor()
{
    Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customizations.Add(new MethodInvoker(new GreedyConstructorQuery()));

    Foo foo = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Foo>();
}
```

The exception thrown is:

> Ploeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException : AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from System.SByte*, most likely because it has no public constructor, is an abstract or non-public type.

So what's that about the SByte*? There's no SByte* in Foo...

Well, yes there is. By placing the MethodInvoker in Customization, it overrides *all* default creation strategies, including the one for strings. Instead, it goes looking for the greediest constructor for string and that is:

```
public String(sbyte* value, int startIndex, int length, Encoding enc);
```

And there's the sbyte*...

---

It's still possible to *replace* the modest constructor selection algorithm with a greedy algorithm, it's just a tad more involved than I first realized.

What you can do is this:

Write a small class like this one:

```
public class GreedyEngineParts : DefaultEngineParts
{
    public override IEnumerator<ISpecimenBuilder> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var iter = base.GetEnumerator();
        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            if (iter.Current is MethodInvoker)
                yield return new MethodInvoker(
                    new CompositeMethodQuery(
                        new GreedyConstructorQuery(),
                        new FactoryMethodQuery()));
            else
                yield return iter.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

and create the Fixture instance like this:

```
Fixture fixture = new Fixture(new GreedyEngineParts());
```

That should work.

Comment: Nice, I like that you can specify the behaviour for a particular type. Thanks

Comment: AutoFixture is actually throwing an ObjectCreationException when I use your second example, with the message "AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from System.SByte*..." My data type is very simple and certainly doesn't depend on a byte*! Is this a bug or have I misused the framework?

Comment: I've just tried, and everything works fine using your first example

Comment: It's not a (known) bug. Can you provide a repro?

Comment: I've sent an email to the address on your blog with a sample solution demoing the behavior. Thank for looking into it.

Comment: Thanks very much for all the follow up work you've provided to this question, Mark.

Comment: @MarkSeemann, should GreedyEngineParts be used most of the time instead of new MethodInvoker( new GreedyConstructorQuery). If yes, please update your blog http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/19/ConstructorstrategiesforAutoFixture/ and add the class to AutoFixture