# Invoking a different constructor with autofixture

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, autofixture

I've got a class that I am testing:

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{

     public ClassUnderTest()
     {
        //do stuff
     }

     public ClassUnderTest(IComplexType complexType)
     {
        //do other stuff
     }

}
```

**When I create my fixture, how do I invoke the constructor that has the IComplexType parameter?** Is this a possibility with autofixture? If not, is there a different framework?

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var mock = fixture.Create<ClassUnderTest(new ComplexType()); //how should this be done?
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/12425521/126014

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/28350054/126014