# AutoFixture can't create immutable object

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, autofixture

I'm coding some tests using AutoFixture in C# 8.0 but I'm had been problems, I guess, about class inheritance.

For example, I have these classes:

```
public class Parent
{
  public Guid Id {get; protected set;}
  public int Age {get; protected set;}

  public void SetAge(int age)
  {
      this.Age = age;
  }
}
```

and the child class

```
public class Child: Parent
{
  public string name {get; private set;}

  private Child() //I Need this because Migrations
  { 
  }
}
```

After it, I use AutoFixture to test my class:

```
 var fixture = new Fixture();
 fixture.Behaviors.Remove(new ThrowingRecursionBehavior());
 fixture.Behaviors
                    .OfType<ThrowingRecursionBehavior>()
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(b => fixture.Behaviors.Remove(b));
fixture.Register<Parent>(() => null);

fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior(recursionDepth: 3));

fixture.Customize<Child>(c => c.FromFactory(new MethodInvoker(new GreedyConstructorQuery())));

fixture.Customize<Child>(ce => ce.Do(x => x.SetAge(10));

var childObject = fixture.Create<Child>();
```

and BOOM! I get an error at the moment when the fixture tries to create the object

```
"AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from the project, most likely because it has no public constructor, is an abstract or non-public type.
```

If I change private for the public constructor in Child class, when I set the Age, the object is created Empty. If I don't use SetAge method, the object is created without problems.

Someone had this problem? Do I need to set some property in AutoFixture when I Use inheritance classes?

Thank you

Comment: Last sentence, " If I don't use SetAge method, the object is created without problems.", are you saying that if you remove the customization above, that calls `SetAge(10)`, but keep the constructor as private, `fixture.Create<Child>();` is able to construct a Child?

Comment: Yes, it is! It's very weird... I found on google this code, but the error continues...

fixture.Register<Parent>(fixture.Create<Parent>);
 fixture.Build<Parent>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, babe!

I found this:

[Force AutoFixture to use the greediest constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425521/force-autofixture-to-use-the-greediest-constructor)

And Gotcha! I solve my problem!